# Video external button won't play on mobile, but works on desktop/mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, video

I'm using flowplayer as my html5 video player (https://flowplayer.org/latest/). I've add an additional button for users to play the video once the user has clicked on it. It works just fine on my laptop or desktop, whenever the user click on that "Play Video" button, the video would play.

However, when I test it on my phone or my friend's phone or any other mobile phone (have tried all iphones and some androids), the video won't play.

And so, I tried to debug with google chrome on my desktop and activate mobile mode. It gives me this error "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined`" on the console whenever I click on that button. But when I exit mobile mode, it works just fine again without giving any errors.

Do you know how can I solve this problem? Thanks.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <!-- player skin -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="skin/functional.css">
        <!-- site specific styling -->
        <style>
        body { font: 12px "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; text-align: center; padding-top: 5%; }
        .flowplayer { width: 80%; }
        </style>
        <!-- for video tag based installs flowplayer depends on jQuery 1.7.2+ -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <!-- include flowplayer -->
        <script src="flowplayer.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- the player -->
        <div>
        <div class="player" style="width:50%;" data-embed="false">
        <!-- <di class="player" data-embed="false" data-swf="flowplayer.swf" data-ratio="0.4167"> -->
            <video id="player">
                <source type="video/webm" src="https://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.webm">
                <source type="video/mp4" src="https://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.mp4">
            </video>
        </div>

        <button id="playbutton">Play Video</button>


        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
<script>
    // run script after document is ready
    $(function () {
        $('#playbutton').click(function(e){
            $('#player').get(0).play();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because Flowplayer changes the HTML of the page when a mobile device is detected. It changes the `video` tag, for this reason your Javascript can't find `#player`. You should use the [Flowplayer Javascript API](https://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html). Here you can find a small example that works on desktop and mobile browsers:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- The "functional" skin - choose from: "functional.css", "minimalist.css", "playful.css" -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.3/skin/functional.css">
        <!-- for video tag based installs flowplayer depends on jQuery 1.7.2+ -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <!-- include flowplayer -->
        <script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.3/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // run script after document is ready
            $(function () {
                $('#playbutton').click(function(e){
                    flowplayer(0).load({
                         sources: [
                           { type: "video/webm", src: "http://stream.flowplayer.org/functional.webm" },
                           { type: "video/mp4",  src: "http://stream.flowplayer.org/functional.mp4" }
                        ]
                      });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- the player -->
        <div>
            <div class="flowplayer" data-ratio="0.4167">
               <video>
                    <source type="video/webm" src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/functional.webm">
                    <source type="video/mp4"  src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/functional.mp4">
               </video>
            </div>
            <button id="playbutton">Play Video</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For more information about the example you can see here:
http://demos.flowplayer.org/api/load.html

Comment: Hi, this definitely works! But what if I want to keep my own format, are there any other solutions for it? Or I just have to stick with this only solution? Thanks!